# Error while copying data from excel file to Postgres table

Tags: postgresql, csv

I have created a table 'person' in the postgres database. 
Used command - 
copy person from '@@path@@' delimiter ',' CSV HEADER;

Error I get - 
invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00

Comment: can you put your full command

Comment: copy <<tablename>> from 'C:\...\filename.csv' delimiter ',' CSV HEADER;

Answer (score 0):

This is what works for me:

```
\Copy (
  SELECT *
  FROM tableName)
To 'C:\path\to\file\fileName.csv' With CSV HEADER;
```